# 2D array of a class object call by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop

I searched a lot on stackoverflow and google but nothing as my case. I want to declare a 2d array of my class box. It works normal, then i need a print function for it. If i printed the array inside main(), it was fine but now with a printer function i seem to get a lot of errors. Please help me with my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>

class box
{
private:
        char life;
public:
       box();
       void display();
       void input_alive();
       void input_dead();
};

box::box() 
{
   life = '0';
}

void box::display()
{
   std::cout << " " <<life <<" ";
}

void box::input_alive()
{
  life = '1';
}

void box::input_dead()
{
 life = '0';
}

void printer(box *array, int yy, int xx)
{
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<yy; i++) //PRINTER
{
   for(j=0; j<xx; j++)
   {
      array[i][j].display();
      if (j+1 == xx) //just newline for separate rows
         std::cout << std::endl;
   }
} 
}
int main()
{
int row=5, col=5;
box arr[row][col];
arr[3][4].input_alive();
arr[1][1].input_alive();

printer(arr, row, col);
return 0;
}
```

this syntax of passing array by reference works fine in normal int/char arrays, but why not here. If i put printer function in main, it works fine :(. Do i have to use new or what? or how do i pass box array into function? thanks.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, C++ doesn't support variable length arrays, so your code is not standards compliant and therefore is not portable.

Second, you can avoid all the pain by using `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

template <size_t ROWS, size_t COLS>
void printer(std::array<box, ROWS>, COLS>& arr)
{
  for(int i=0; i<ROW; ++i)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<COL; ++j)
    {
      // do something with arr[i][j]
    }
}

int main()
{
  const int row=5;
  const int col=5;
  std::array<std::array<box, row>, col> arr;
  arr[3][4].input_alive();
  arr[1][1].input_alive();

  printer(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, but what do you mean by variable length arrays? Isn't arr[5][5] constant?

Comment: @ShoaibHaider You have `box arr[row][col];`, and neither `row` nor `col` are compile time constants. They are in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to forget about raw arrays. Instead, you use `std::vector` or `std::array` and write a Matrix class with `operator()`, as explained in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html). See also the next item in the FAQ for reasons why you'd want to prefer the `(x, y)` form to `[x][y]`, but consider that there *are* good programmers who prefer the latter syntax (using a proxy class), so the case is perhaps not as clear as the FAQ says it is.

In any case, you need a Matrix class with a `std::vector` or `std::array` implementation. Raw arrays are the wrong tool for this task.